# Recommended ways to automatically update several word documents with specific info

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have several word documents (20+) that need to be updated with info like dates, names, addresses, titles. What are some recommended ways to automatically update all of them?

Ideally, I would like to just fill the data in an Excel Spreadsheet, and have all word documents automatically update with the info.

Comment: And  what have you actually done to achieve this? What code can you show or share? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am looking for recommended ways to solve my problem. I can search in google ways to solve it, however there are many, and I don't have the time to try them out. That is why I'm asking. I searched for similar questions in this site, but didn't find any.

Comment: @JorgeH please see what you are asking us: "I don't want to spend time doing this myself, so I'm going to ask others to spend time telling me what I know I can learn on my own". This site expects people to have tried solving things themselves and demonstrate that, in order to respect the community that answers these questions. I assume you do not mean to sound the way your post did, but that was its plain meaning.

Answer (score -1):

### Mail Merge

[Mail Merge Using an Excel Spreadsheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)

I do this on a daily basis.
It sort of stands the idea of a mass mailing on its head.

A row in your spreadsheet is your data record.
You can apply it to multiple documents.

Comment: Thank you. This might be helpful, however I'll have to open each document and generate the new personalized document each time I update the Excel. This option is useful if I have few documents and require many variations of each. For me, its the other way around: I have many documents and require few variations of each.

Comment: That is what I do. If you have a group of documents that you want to update at once you could have a macro that lets you create new merge documents from each in the group and pick a record to use for merging each. I have over 100 documents that use this process, however it is rare that I am using more than three at a time.